# Looping Through DOM Objects for Click

Tags: jquery, dom, coffeescript

I have Ruby/Rails code that generates a set of links based on a DB pull.  The resulting links look like this:

```
<a href="/show_device_dialog" id="show_device_dialog_1">Call Customer 1</a> 
<br />
<a href="/show_device_dialog" id="show_device_dialog_28">Call Customer 28</a> 
<br />
```

When a user clicks a linke, I want to pop a dialog open to verify a couple of options before moving on.  To do that, I am trying to trap the 'click' event using UJS.  What I do is parse the content for "A" objects with an "id" containing "show_device_dialog_" and then try and hook a function to them that pops the dialog.

Now, I'm fairly new to this, so I'm doing a bit of it by brute force:

```
$(document).ready ->
  console.log "building show_device_dialog..."
  $("a[id^='show_device_dialog_']").each ->
    console.log "...loop..."
    @click (e) ->
      dialog_form = undefined
      url = undefined
      dialog_form = undefined
      url = undefined
      url = $(this).attr("href")
      dialog_form = $("<div id=\"dialog-form-"+@id+"\">Loading form...</div>").dialog(
        autoOpen: false
        width: 520
        modal: true
        open: ->
          $(this).load url + " #content"

        close: ->
          $("#dialog-form"+@id).remove()
      )
      dialog_form.dialog "open"
      e.preventDefault()

    console.log "...done*"
```

When the page is loaded, on the console I see:

```
building show_device_dialog... contacts.js:3
...loop... contacts.js:5
...done* contacts.js:28
...loop... contacts.js:5
...done* contacts.js:28
```

Which suggests that the two links are being found and handled.  However, what happens is that links do not seem to have the "click" trigger associated with them.  In addition, a spurious new browser window opens as though one of the links had been clicked.

The pop code itself, without the multi-link searching block, works fine and is verified to do what I want.  So, the issue is in how I am handling the "found" DOM object, I think.

Can someone point me in the right direction about where my mistake is here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

> **.each( function(index, Element) )**
>
> [...] the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element,
>   so the keyword `this` refers to the element.

So inside your `$("a[id^='show_device_dialog_']").each` callback, `@` is the raw DOM element, not a jQuery wrapped version. That means that you're calling the DOM element's [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.click) method, not jQuery's. You want to say:

```
$("a[id^='show_device_dialog_']").each ->
  console.log "...loop..."
  $(@).click (e) ->
    #...
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/An7CM/

Comment: Thank you.  I totally missed that.  Answer correct, problem solved, and happily accepted.